# `Error: Output is not defined` when passing value outside a directive to parent directive

Tags: events, output, angular

I have an root-app component which is defined like this in the template.

```
template: `
<dev-table (complete)="onSelect(developer)"></dev-table>
<dev-details [selectedDeveloper]="selectedDeveloper"></dev-details>
`
directives: [DevDetailsComponent, DevTableComponent],
providers: [DevValueService, provide(DevService, {useClass: DevService})]
```

is a list and on selection of one of the internal list it should send the value of the list (developer) which is passed into  as selected developer. @Input is defined right and is taken into  correctly. But the @output is giving an error `Error: Output is not defined` What definition is needed or what is the definition method. I am missing something.

This is the class definition:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dev-table',
  template: `
    <ul class="dev">
      <li *ngFor="#developer of developers"
        [class.selected]="developer === selectedDeveloper;this.complete.next();"
        (click)="onSelect(developer)">
        <span class="spanbackground">{{developer.name}}</span> -  {{developer.skill}}
      </li>
    </ul>  
  `, 
  providers: [DevService]
})

export class DevTableComponent implements OnInit{
    public developers : Developer[];
    public selectedDeveloper : Developer;
    constructor(private _DevService: DevService) { }
    @Output() complete = new EventEmitter(); 
    public onSelect(developer: Developer) { this.selectedDeveloper = developer; }
    getDevelopers(){
      this._DevService.getDevelopers().then(developers => this.developers = developers)
    }
    ngOnInit(){
      this.getDevelopers();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:** The final working code did not have `developer === selectedDeveloper;this.complete.next();` rather `this.complete.next()` was put into the onSelect function.

Comment: Did you add this? `import {Output} from "angular2/core";`

Comment: Thank you. I did that and am getting `Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at column 33 in [developer === selectedDeveloper;this.complete.next();] in DevTableComponent@3:8 ` . What I am technically doing is passing the value of developer to parent component. and then passing it as input to <dev-details> .dev-details is working correctly isolated. But unable to capture the event sent with value.

Comment: You can't add that much code into the template, you must add all that logic into a function that returns a boolean and call it like this: `[class.selected]="shouldSelect()"`

Comment: Okay Thanks. Do I also have to import `EventEmitter`? Getting undefined error. Isnt that part of the component.

Comment: Yea. Any class you are using you have to import it. OnInit, Developer, DevService ...

Comment: Thanks that resolved. I am not getting the selected value from internal list however. I am also doing `this.complete.emit(someValue);`

Comment: try `onSelect($event)` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the value to the parent component you can leverage custom event. This code is located in the template of the parent component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <dev-table (complete)="someMethod($event.value)"></dev-table>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  someMethod(value) {
    console.log('complete event - value = ' + value);
  }
}
```

To trigger the event, you could do something like that in your child component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    (...)
    <span (click)="triggerCompleteEvent()">Trigger complete event</span>
  `
})
export class DevTableComponent implements OnInit{
  @Output()
  complete:EventEmitter;

  constructor() {
    this.complete = new EventEmitter();
  }

  triggerCompleteEvent() {
    this.complete.emit(someValue);
  }
}
```

`someValue` corresponds to the value you want the event contains and event subscribes can get.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Is this function complete supposed to be in the parent directive or the actual directive. $event.value is some value in my list within the directive.

Comment: Value captured and event is triggered right. But the parent is coming undefined. `<ul class="dev"><li *ngFor="#developer of developers"
        [class.selected]="developer !== selectedDeveloper"
        (click)="onSelect(developer)"><span class="spanbackground">{{developer.name}}</span> -  {{developer.skill}}
      </li></ul>  ` and class has `onSelect(developer: Developer) { 
        this.selectedDeveloper = developer;console.log(this.selectedDeveloper);this.complete.emit(this.selectedDeveloper);
    } ` . In parent `<dev-table (complete)="onSelect($event.value)"></dev-table>`

Comment: Safely passing the data now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"@output is giving an error Error: Output is not defined What definition is needed or what is the definition method. I am missing something." :

`import {Output} from "angular2/core";`

You have to import the definition of any class you are using.

Comment: All worked and the code is working now. I have defined the event within the child directive. The data is captured on click (console.log works fine). I am able to pass events correctly from within the directive - no errors generated. using `this.complete.emit(someValue);` but I am not able to capture the event in the parent component `<dev-table (complete)="onSelect($event.value)"></dev-table>` It gives $event.value as undefined in parent. Is there a capture process that is different?

Comment: just `$event` not `$event.value`

Comment: console.log is undefined.

Comment: you might want to update your code to the way you have it now