# How to show parent component properties in a child component [angular2]

Tags: angular

I want a given component to be able to reference its parent component. Actually, I have some application state (an option selected by the user) that I want to be able to use from anywhere within the application. Which is the best pattern: a) reference the property on my component's parent component or b) somehow make the application state available globally to all components. And how would this look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something needs to shared across the application, it better be encapsulated into a service and registered during the bootstrapping process.

```
export class AppService {
  private _state:any;
  set(state){
   this.state=state;
  }
  get() {
   return this._state
  }
}
```

Register it during bootstrap

```
bootstrap(App,[AppService]);
```

And inject it in both Parent and Child component. Parent calls `set` and child calls `get`

In case if the state is just local to the component then you can use simple property binding input as @Sasxa pointed out.

Comment: I ended up using this strategy and it's working great.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value from parent to child via property binding/input properties, like so:

```
<parent>
  <child [state]="value">

class Parent {
  public value = 123;
}

class Child {
  @Input() state;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(state);
  }
}
```

And for b), I would highly recommend [`@ngrx/store`](https://github.com/ngrx/store).

Answer (score 0):

I would see several ways to do that:

- Create an `@Input` in the child component to provide the value to display. See this link for more details: [`Error: Output is not defined` when passing value outside a directive to parent directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808134/error-output-is-not-defined-when-passing-value-outside-a-directive-to-parent/34808248#34808248)
- Inject the parent component instance into the child one. This way the child component will have access to the parent properties. See this answer for more details: [Angular2 Exception: No provider for Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451069/angular2-exception-no-provider-for-service/35451209#35451209)
- Use a shared service with dedicated properties to make communicate parent and child components. See this link for more details: [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-in-angular2/34402436)